# How to set expiration date on Key Vault secret by calling api

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am calling the keyvault API to set new secrets and indeed it works fine, meaning that the secret appears correctly except the expiration date is not there.

```
$expiryDate = ((Get-Date).AddMonths(3)).ToFileTimeUtc()
$body =  @{
    "value"       = $KeyValue
    "contentType" = $KeyType
    "exp"         = $expiryDate
} | ConvertTo-Json

$params = @{
    "Uri"     = "https://$($KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/secrets/$($KeyName)?api-version=7.0"
    "Method"  = "Put"
    "Headers" = @{
        'Authorization' = $Authorization
        "Accept"        = "application/json"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    }
    "Body" = $body
}
```

The only thing I may think about from the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/updatesecret/updatesecret#secretattributes) is that it wants an Integer, while I am not sure that the Get-Date returns an Integer at all.

In the current solution I have tried to cast it to an integer by using **ToFileTimeUtc**
and before that I simply tried **ToUniversalTime** but both are not working.
Again, the secret appears on the key vault but the expiration date is seems not being set there:

[image]

As last remark, I would like to stick to the REST API call instead of using **az** Azure CLI.

Comment: It looks like you need to [convert it to a unix timestamp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/147a91cca49415e66a55d4b80db226c78d888fce/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys/src/KeyAttributes.cs#L54-L55)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you first of all for the comment! I tried to pass directly 1620821776 as a value in the powershell script, which should be the time in seconds pointing to May 2021 (this is what I am trying to achieve through the script). But nothing..

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen solution was in my wrong nested json but without your comment I wouldn't have made it anyway :) thanks a lot!

Comment: That's great, and you're welcome! Post an answer with the solution :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
# UNIX Epoch is January 1st, 1970 at 12:00 AM
$unixEpoch = Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970"
$expiryDate = ((Get-Date).AddMonths(3)).ToUniversalTime()
$unixExpiryDate = (New-TimeSpan -Start $unixEpoch -End 
$expiryDate).TotalSeconds

$attributes = @{
"exp" = $unixExpiryDate
}

$body =  @{     
    "value"       = $KeyValue
    "contentType" = $KeyType
    "attributes"  = $attributes
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

Solution contains 2 parts:

1. The json was wrongly constructed and needs a nested "attributes" node
2. as pointed out in the comment of my question, credits to @Mathias R. Jessen ,
   it expects a date in UNIX format: